# Бот не высылает текстовый документ с ответом

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Когда юзер нажимает "товар в наличии",бот должен отправлять ему файл с текстом
посмотрел в инете вроде команду  правильно написал
ошибок не выдает , но как надо не делает
Кто подскажет что не так ?)

```
import telebot


from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Просмотр Товара")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("товар в наличии")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Профиль ")

    markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

    ...


        elif message.text == 'товар в наличии':

            def send_file(message):
                doc = open('D:/Товар.docx', 'rb')
                bot.send_document(message.chat.id, doc)
                bot.send_document(message.chat.id, "FILEID")
```

Comment: какую команду правильно написал?

Answer (score 1):

рабочий пример:

```
f = open('/opt/bot/files/test.bat', 'rb')
bot.send_document(message.chat.id, f, None, 'Caption')
f.close()
```